# Connection Multiplexing

Tags: connection, tunnel, multiplexing

Supposing we have opened a connection of type either TCP or UDP to another remote machine. Having this connection, can we allow multiple connections virtually over this connection like VPN(but not VPN)? I mean multiple applications run on remote machine and you try to access to these applications, is there any multiplexing mechanism or concept supporting such feature?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is also known as [tunneling protocol](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tunneling_protocol), and various applications implement that for various protocols. I personally like OpenSSH - see [here](http://www.freebsd.org/doc/handbook/openssh.html#SECURITY-SSH-TUNNELING).